# Как команды вынести в отдельный файл?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть код:

```
import telebot
import time
import config
import messages
from handler_image import handler



bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start','help'])
def handler_start_help(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, messages.START)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['gray'])
def handler_gray(message):
    global users
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    users[chat_id] = "gray"
    bot.send_message(chat_id,messages.SEND_PHOTO)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['sepia'])
def handler_sepia(message):
    global users
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    users[chat_id] = "sepia"
    bot.send_message(chat_id,messages.SEND_PHOTO)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['negative'])
def handler_negative(message):
    global users
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    users[chat_id] = "negative"
    bot.send_message(chat_id,messages.SEND_PHOTO)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['uproar'])
def handler_uproar(message):
    global users
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    users[chat_id] = "uproar"
    bot.send_message(chat_id,messages.SEND_PHOTO)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['mono'])
def handler_mono(message):
    global users
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    users[chat_id] = "mono"
    bot.send_message(chat_id,messages.SEND_PHOTO)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[0].file_id)
        r = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        img = handler.ImageHandler(r)
        if users[chat_id] == "gray":
            out = img.gray()
            bot.send_photo(chat_id, out)
        if users[chat_id] == "sepia":
            out = img.sepia()
            bot.send_photo(chat_id, out)
        if users[chat_id] == "negative":
            out = img.negative()
            bot.send_photo(chat_id, out)
        if users[chat_id] == "uproar":
            out = img.uproar()
            bot.send_photo(chat_id, out)
        if users[chat_id] == "mono":
            out = img.mono()
            bot.send_photo(chat_id, out)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message,e)

def main():
    users = {}
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Как мне вынести функции handler_* , handle_docs_photo, handler_start_help в отдельный файл commands.py?

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так

```
root:
  - main.py # ваш главный файл в данном случае
  - commands.py
```

В файле main.py добавьте

```
from .commands import handle_docs_photo # и другие функции
```

или

```
from .commands import * # чтобы импортировать всё сразу
```

Comment: А как мне bot передать? И что с декоратором делать? Я же не напишу 
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])\n
    handle_docs_photo

Comment: @AminevTimur перенесите bot и все импорты связанные с ним в тот отдельный файл command.py, а в main оставьте только вызовы def main()